# Team foundation build service new agent

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I accedently removed 2 build agents on the server. I added them again in the administration console (and connected them to the same build controller again).

In the properties of my build I checked the properties to see if anything changed but he still connects to the same controller.

When I now do queue build I got this error and I don't know why:

TF203059: The Label 20120905.1@[file] already exists. Retry the command with a different label name.

I looked on the internet and everybody that has this problem is using the parrallel template but I'm using the default template.

Can anyone help me?

Kind regards,

Thibault Heylen

Comment: Did you try removing the existing label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like automatic labels are being created on build.  You can disable labeling in the build definition if you want.  You can also remove the existing label by going to the location in source control explorer.  Once you find it, view history, then view labels, then remove the problematic label.